# Virtualization to work around hardware driver issues?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, drivers, canon-lide

My scanner Canoscan LIDE 100 only works under windows. My main o/s is ubuntu. Whenever I have to scan, I have to boot to windows.

On the ubuntu host I have a virtualbox - windows xp guest, which works great (faster than the usual windows :).

Is there a way I can get the scanner work under my virtual-windows? But the basic question is, can the virtualization be used to work around the hardware driver issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3teSzoXpNA

and

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9462309#post9462309

Comment: First link shows no driver installation, only how to configure VM to use the host's USB.  Second link says use XSane.  Not only is it a page slap, it isn't the answer to the title question: how to use virtualization to get around driver support of a host.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the PUEL edition of VirtualBox. After installing that Virtual Windows install should be be to access the scanner

Comment: I see USB support is closed source. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @anant yes, USB support is closed source.